# Запрет ввода букв в текстбокс

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Тут возникла проблема. В текстбокс записывается номер телефона и вносится в файл(после нажатия кнопки). Хотелось бы запретить ввод букв в текстбокс.
П.С. Думал насчет проверки на буквы. Но так как у меня еще есть один текстбокс который записывает ФИО в туже строку куда и номер то этот вариант пролетает...

---

```
procedure Form2.textBox1_KeyPress(sender: Object; e: KeyPressEventArgs);
    var key:char;
begin
   begin
   if not (Key in ['0'..'9', #8]) then
   Key := #0;
end;
end;
```

Так же? Что то не работает... По идее когда я ввожу буквы они не должны вводится?

Comment: @Sin2p
Нет, не так. Вы проверяете значение не инициализированной локальной переменной. Как оно должно работать по вашему?

Код нажатой клавиши должен содержаться во входном параметре `e`. Смотрите в справке что там есть в `KeyPressEventArgs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

обработчик нажатия клавиши в текст боксе:

```
begin
  if not (Key in ['0'..'9', #8]) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```